# array_map unlink file named ..txt

Tags: php

I use this method

```
array_map('unlink', glob("data/words/*.*"));
```

To delete all files Including all `.txt` extension and It works well

But when there is a file named `..txt` is not deleted

Comment: is this a linux based OS? usually files starting with `.` in Linux are considered hidden and are often excluded from glob results

Comment: do you want to delete only `txt` files with one or more `.` preceeding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that glob('*') ignores all 'hidden' files by default. This means it does not return files that start with a dot (e.g. **.file**).

If you want to match those files too, you can use "{,.}*" as the pattern with the `GLOB_BRACE` flag.

```
<?php
// Search for all files that match .* or *
$files = glob('{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
?>
```

Specifically in your case, this should work.

```
array_map('unlink', glob("data/words/{,.}*",GLOB_BRACE));
```

Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#68869